# How to return the number of HTML list elements on change using an event listener in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My todo list appends every input value starting with the number of elements in the list. So, entering the first item "Do homework" outputs to "1. Do homework." And the second input "Learn JS" outputs to "2. Learn JS." However, when deleting an element in the middle of the list, the number adjacent to the item doesn't adjust accordingly to the number of current list elements.

For example, if the output is:

> 1. Do homework 
> 2. Learn JS
> 3. Practice piano

Deleting number 2 will return:

> 1. Do homework 
> 3. Practice piano

Instead of the correct output:

> 1. Do homework 
> 2. Practice piano

```js
var listset = document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', newItem);


function newItem() {


  var lilist = document.getElementById("listForm").getElementsByTagName("li")
  var largo = lilist.length + 1
  var node = document.createElement('li');
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value

  const delButton = document.createElement('img')
  delButton.src = "https://www.upload.ee/image/14249875/delete-button.jpg"
  delButton.width = 15;
  delButton.height = 15;



 delButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.target.closest('li').remove()
  })

  
 

  var textNode = document.createTextNode(largo +'. '+ inputValue + " ");

  node.appendChild(textNode)


  if (inputValue !== '') {
    var item = document.getElementById('listForm').appendChild(node);
    item.appendChild(delButton)
    document.getElementById('input').value = '';
  }


 



}
```

```css
h1 {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

.header2 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}



.main-page {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

li {
    margin-top: 10px;
}



.list {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: -151px;
}


#input {
    font-size: 18px;
}

#add {
    background-color: rgb(233, 235, 235);
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: -3px;
}


#listForm {
    color: black;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 284px;

}

li {
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

li:hover {
    cursor: grab;
    color: rgb(176, 171, 171)

}


#listForm .checked {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.unchecked {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To Do List: Raamis Ali</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A todo list application">
    <meta name="author" content="Raamis Ali">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="list.css"> </head>

<body>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <div class="main-page">
        <h1>To Do List Web App</h1>
        <p class="header2">Created by Raamis Ali</p>
        <div class="list">
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add items">
            <input type="button" value="Add" id="add" onclick="newItem()"> </div>
        <ul id="listForm"> 
      </ul>
        <br> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried implementing this event listener and function with different variations of this but I have had no success:

```
largo.addEventListener('change', updateValue())
function updateValue(e) {
var lilist = document.getElementById("listForm").getElementsByTagName("li")
lilist.length + 1 == e.target.value;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `<ol>` instead of `<ul>`? Then the numbers will be created automatically by the browser and you don't have to do it in code.

Comment: @Barmar I initially switched to ordered lists in the midst of my project but it made other CSS elements on the page format differently so I figured I could program this through JavaScript to save the hassle of going back to figure it. Not a good decision on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure the number will not change, because you didn't re-initialize the list text with new numeric values.

As @Barmar suggest, it would better to use "ol" element instead of "ul" which will output the correct numeric order of the list.

```js
var listset = document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', newItem);


function newItem() {


  var lilist = document.getElementById("listForm").getElementsByTagName("li")
  var node = document.createElement('li');
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value

  const delButton = document.createElement('img')
  delButton.src = "https://www.upload.ee/image/14249875/delete-button.jpg"
  delButton.width = 15;
  delButton.height = 15;



 delButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.target.closest('li').remove()
  })

  
 

  var textNode = document.createTextNode(inputValue + " ");

  node.appendChild(textNode)


  if (inputValue !== '') {
    var item = document.getElementById('listForm').appendChild(node);
    item.appendChild(delButton)
    document.getElementById('input').value = '';
  }


 



}
```

```css
h1 {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

.header2 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}



.main-page {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}


ol {
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

li {
    margin-top: 10px;
}



.list {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: -151px;
}


#input {
    font-size: 18px;
}

#add {
    background-color: rgb(233, 235, 235);
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: -3px;
}


#listForm {
    color: black;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 284px;

}

li {
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

li:hover {
    cursor: grab;
    color: rgb(176, 171, 171)

}


#listForm .checked {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.unchecked {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To Do List: Raamis Ali</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A todo list application">
    <meta name="author" content="Raamis Ali">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="list.css"> </head>

<body>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <div class="main-page">
        <h1>To Do List Web App</h1>
        <p class="header2">Created by Raamis Ali</p>
        <div class="list">
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add items">
            <input type="button" value="Add" id="add" onclick="newItem()"> </div>
        <ol id="listForm"> 
      </ol>
        <br> </div>
</body>

</html>
```